# Exploding Array in Batches of size 'n'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Looking to explode a nested array w/ Spark into batches. The column below is a nested array from an XML files. Now attempting to write the time series data into batches in order to write over to a NoSQL database. For example:

```
+-------+-----------------------+
|   ID  |               Example |
+-------+-----------------------+
|      A|   [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] |
+-------+-----------------------+
```

Output with batches of size 2

```
+-------+-----------------------+
|   ID  |               Example |
+-------+-----------------------+
|      A|         [[1,2],[3,4]] |
+-------+-----------------------+
|      A|               [[5,6]] |
+-------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: can you share the schema of your input dataframe and if possible of the expected dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### For Spark v 2.1+

You can take advantage of [`pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode) to explode your column along with the index it appears in your array and then divide the resultant position by `n` to create groups.

For example, here is the output of using `posexplode()` on your DataFrame:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.select('ID', f.posexplode('Example')).show()
#+---+---+------+
#| ID|pos|   col|
#+---+---+------+
#|  A|  0|[1, 2]|
#|  A|  1|[3, 4]|
#|  A|  2|[5, 6]|
#+---+---+------+
```

Notice that we get two columns: `pos` and `col` instead of just one. Since we want groups of `n`, we can simply divide the `pos` by `n` and take the `floor` to get groups.

```python
n = 2
df.select('ID', f.posexplode('Example'))\
    .withColumn("group", f.floor(f.col("pos")/n))\
    .show(truncate=False)
#+---+---+------+-----+
#|ID |pos|col   |group|
#+---+---+------+-----+
#|A  |0  |[1, 2]|0    |
#|A  |1  |[3, 4]|0    |
#|A  |2  |[5, 6]|1    |
#+---+---+------+-----+
```

Now group by the `"ID"` and the `"group"` and use [`pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list) to get your desired output.

```python
df.select('ID', f.posexplode('Example'))\
    .withColumn("group", f.floor(f.col("pos")/n))\
    .groupBy("ID", "group")\
    .agg(f.collect_list("col").alias("Example"))\
    .sort("group")\
    .drop("group")\
    .show(truncate=False)
#+---+----------------------------------------+
#|ID |Example                                 |
#+---+----------------------------------------+
#|A  |[WrappedArray(1, 2), WrappedArray(3, 4)]|
#|A  |[WrappedArray(5, 6)]                    |
#+---+----------------------------------------+
```

You'll see that I also sorted by the `"group"` column and dropped it, but this is optional depending on your needs.

---

#### For Older Versions of Spark

There are some other methods for Spark versions below 2.1. All of these methods produce the same output as above.

**1. Using `udf`**

You can use a `udf` to break your array into groups. For example:

```python
def get_groups(array, n):
    return filter(lambda x: x, [array[i*n:(i+1)*n] for i in range(len(array))])

get_groups_of_2 = f.udf(
    lambda x: get_groups(x, 2),
    ArrayType(ArrayType(ArrayType(IntegerType())))
)

df.select("ID", f.explode(get_groups_of_2("Example")).alias("Example"))\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

The `get_groups()` function will take an array and return an array of groups of n elements.

**2. Using `rdd`**

Another option is to serialize to `rdd` and use the `get_groups()` function inside of a call to `map()`. Then convert back to a DataFrame. You'll have to specify the schema for this conversion to work properly.

```python
n = 2

schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("ID", StringType()),
        StructField("Example", ArrayType(ArrayType(ArrayType(IntegerType()))))
    ]
)

df.rdd.map(lambda x: (x["ID"], get_groups(x["Example"], n=n)))\
    .toDF(schema)\
    .select("ID", f.explode("Example").alias("Example"))\
    .show(truncate=False)
```